# Connect Redshift PostgreSQL through Node and Meteor

Tags: node.js, postgresql, meteor, amazon-redshift

I have tried pg and other modules and packages to **connect Redshift PostgreSQL through Node and Meteor**.

This is my recent code written in node. It is **unable to connect to Redshift**. The `client.connect` function never responds.

But if I try to connect to some other PostgreSQL server, like localhost or some other remote server, then the code works as expected.

> Same is the problem with **Meteor**.

```
var pg = require('pg');

var conString = "postgres://User:Password@EndPoint/Database";
//var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres";

console.log("Started...");

var client = new pg.Client(conString);

console.log("Client", client);

client.connect(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
  }
  client.query('SELECT NOW() AS "theTime"', function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    console.log(result.rows[0].theTime);
    //output: Tue Jan 15 2013 19:12:47 GMT-600 (CST) 
    client.end();
  });
});

console.log("End...");
```

> I want to connect through **Meteor**. But if not possible through Meteor,
>   **Node.js** will also work.

Comment: Did you update in the security group the IP of the connecting server?

Comment: Yes I have updated the group. Its getting connect via psql through terminal.